# Set field in mongoose document to array length

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongoose document (Mongoose 5.4.13, mongoDB 4.0.12):

```
var SkillSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    skill: { type: String },
    count: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    associatedUsers: [{ type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
});
```

That I update as follows:

```
var query = { skill: req.body.skill };
var update = { $addToSet: { associatedUsers: req.params.id } };
            
var options = { upsert: true, new: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true };

await skillSchema.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options);
```

During this update, I would like to also update `count` to be equal to the length of `associatedUsers`.

Ideally I want this to happen at the same time as updating the other fields (i.e not in a subsequent update), either via a [pre-hook](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre) or within `findOneAndUpdate`.

I've tried using a pre hook after schema definition:

```
SkillSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', async function(){
    console.log("counting associated users");
    this.count = this.associatedUsers.length;
    next();
});
```

As well as using [aggregate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate) in my UPDATE route:

```
await skillSchema.aggregate([{ $project: { count: { $size: "$associatedUsers" } } } ])
```

But I can't get either to work.

**Does anyone have any suggestions for how I could achieve this**?

Comment: Did the answers below help you?

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/command/update/index.html#update-command-example-agg) like this in 4.2 which supports aggregation pipeline in update.

The first $set stage calculates a `associatedUsers` based on the previous and new value. [`$setUnion`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) to keep the distinct associatedUsers values.

The second $set stage calculates `tally` based on the `associatedUsers` calculated in the previous stage.[`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) to calculate the length of associatedUsers values.

```
var query = {skill: req.body.skill};
var update = [{ $set: { "associatedUsers":{"$setUnion":[{"$ifNull":["$associatedUsers",[]]}, [req.params.id]] }}}, {$set:{tally:{ $size: "$associatedUsers" }}}];
var options = { upsert: true, new: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true };
await skillSchema.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options)
```

If any argument resolves to a value of null or refers to a field that is missing, $setUnion returns null. So just needed to safeguard our operation with [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/)

Comment: This looks like an excellent solution. I will test this tonight

Comment: in case of upsert, it'll give error arguement to $size must be an array

Comment: @sushantmehta Thanks.  Updated answer to account for null values in the set operation. That is behavior for set operators not specially related to upsert.

Comment: This isn't working for me: `var update = [{ $set: { "associatedUsers":{"$setUnion":[{"$ifNull":["$associatedUsers",[] ]}, [req.params.id]] }}}, { $set: { count: { $size: "$associatedUsers" }}}];`   Note: I've changed the schema field `tally` to `count`. Will update the question to reflect this

Comment: what version are you on ? both mongoose and mongodb server. this works for me in the mongodb 4.2 version. what is the error you see if any ? you can run mongoose with `mongoose.set('debug', true);` to see what queries are sent over to mongodb

Comment: Mongoose 5.4.13, mongoDB 4.0.12. I'm on their free tier and looks like I'm stuck with 4.0.12. I didn't receive an error previously, it just didn't change the tally after updating. Will try again today. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Np. Sorry, expressive updates is a new feature in 4.2. It will not work with older version. You probably have to do in multiple queries.

Answer (score 2):

About tally and associatedUsers.length

```
// define your schema object
var schemaObj = {
  skill: { type: String },
  associatedUsers: { type: Array }
};

// get the length of users
var lengthOfAsUsers = schemaObj.associatedUsers.length;

// add tally to schema object and set default to the length of users
schemaObj.tally = { type: Number, default: lengthOfAsUsers };

// and pass your schema object to mongoose.Schema
var SkillSchema = new mongoose.Schema(schemaObj);

module.exports = SkillSchema;
```

EDIT 
you can update tally subsequently, but recommended solution would be to use this method
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

```
const id = "nameSomeId";

SkillSchema.find({ _id: id }).then(resp => {
  const tallyToUpdate = resp.associatedUsers.length;
  SkillSchema.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, { tally: tallyToUpdate }).then(
    resp => {
      console.log(resp);
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: But is this dynamic? I.e will the tally increase as I add `associatedUsers`?

Comment: Well, you can always update tally subsucvently..
I will edit my answer

Comment: sure, but this require I make two requests which is not efficient

Answer (score 1):

The solution I have will only work on mongodb v 4.2 as it has option to use aggregate in the update and will only need one query as:

```
skillSchemafindOneAndUpdate(


 {skill:"art"},
   [
     { $set: { 
       associatedUsers:{
         $cond:{
            if: {$gte: [{$indexOfArray: ["$associatedUsers", mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)]}, 0]},
              then: "$associatedUsers",
              else: { $cond:{
                if: { $isArray: "$associatedUsers" },
                then: {$concatArrays:["$associatedUsers",[mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)]]},
                else: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)]
           }}
           }
      }}},
      {$set:{
        associatedUsers:"$associatedUsers",
        tally:{$size:"$associatedUsers"},
      }}
   ],
   {upsert:true,new:true}
)
```

ref: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-with-aggregation-pipeline

Answer (score 0):

The "Group" field does not appear in the schema. On MongoDB Shell, these codes will work.

However, Mongoose will also give an error because the schema is validated.

Is the "Group" field a dynamic field? I think the problem with the schema will be solved.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var SkillSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    skill: { type: String },
    tally: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    associatedUsers: { type: Array },
    group: { type: Array }
 });
```